# Rstudio Error : mismatched input '''. Expecting: <expression>

Tags: sql, r, syntax, rstudio

Below is my code :

```
select id from hdb.h_summary h
where 
h.name  like '%DEMO%' 
or h.name  like '%Demo%' 
or h.name  like '%TEST%'
or h.name  like '%Test%'
```

When running, I'm getting the below error :

```
mismatched input '''. Expecting: <expression>
```

Please let me know if there is some basic mistake I'm making. I've tried placing all my conditions in parentheses as well [Example - or h.name  like ('%Test%')] but that has not worked.

I think there is some package which is not installed on my Rstudio which is limiting me here. If so, please let me know which package can resolve this.

Comment: That syntax is perfectly valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: Please post the full R code even if running R markdown that implements this SQL statement.